# genetic algorithm - fitness function

Tags: neural-network, genetic-algorithm

I'm trying to wrap my head around genetic algorithms and neural networks and have seen several videos on the web. Some of them are pathfinding algorithms like the mouse that searches the cheese.

The fitness function gives a sort of score to each mouse to rate how they are performing.  in an empty room the distance from the mouse to the cheese would be a good indicator of the fitness score because they can "see" the cheese and have to learn to go there.. But, in a room filled with boxes, what would be a good fitness function? the distance would assume that they know in what direction to go, because if I give a score to those that reduce the distance then eventually all mice will go in that direction... If I move the cheese to another location they will go crazy... Simply the distance they moved is also not good, becuase one that is moving in circles would have a high score...

What would be a good fitness function for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you are not mixing genetic algorithms with traditional pathfinding algorithms? Both have sort of a fitness function. In the case of pathfinding, "heuristic" is often what it's called. For those algorithms, the "fitness" has to be **assumed** to use while executing the algorithm (or more like to speed it up).

The fitness function in actual genetic algorithms is relatively exact but that's because it is usually more of an evaluation.
For example you perform the simulation with the current values and compute how long it took for the mouse to find the cheese. That time or distance traveled is the inverse fitness (inverse because larger number means less fit).
If the fitness was better than previous runs, you can branch off new simulations with slightly different settings (generated via mutation, randomness etc.) and evaluate each time what improves the fitness and what doesn't (-> Survival of the fittest). If the fitness was worse, give this branch up (or maybe keep it only every XX times you encounter a bad branch; "possibly it is on a good way").

Comment: Thank you! very clear..  So a decent fitness function could for example be the inverse time + "sectors of the map" explored? where inverse time has a higher value, but the explored sectors would reward those that at least moved without crashing in the early gereations.. does that make any sense?

Comment: the idea would be that the mouses run around like crazy, exploring the map and searching the cheese. and as soon as the mouse "sees" the cheese, it should run for it.. so for example the inputs could be 8 rays that measure the distance to the walls in all directions, 1 input that tells if the cheese is in line of sight, 1 for the mouse to cheese distance, and one for the angle.

Comment: By crashing you mean that you have actual physics simulations and you want to prevent the mouse from touching the walls for example? That makes things a bit tricky because the mouse will inevitably need more time to explore more sectors, so those two fitness values work against each other. I think those are two separatable problems. Separately teach the mouse to take a few preprogrammed corners while avoiding to crash, and then later use those fixed "wall avoidance settings" to geneticaly determine the settings for the pathfinding component.

Comment: Okey nevermind then, you have no physics. What you want to prevent is that the mouse uselessly re-explores the same sectors, right? Then don't reward exploring new sectors but punish staying too long in the same sector!

Answer (score 0):

Number of steps required to reach the cheese perhaps?

Notice that your problem is clasically solved with the [A* algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) which is not evolutionary. It does use an [heuristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heuristic_(computer_science)) to have a hint on how good is a position.

However, a fitness function should aim to optimize your end result, but you don't necessarily need to have it's "correct" or "best" value before hand. Just find something that you know works on "the more the better" or "the less the better" basis.